# Pipe image using node-request but abort on non-200 http status code

Tags: node.js, node-request

I'm trying to pipe an image stored on Amazon S3 using [node-request](https://github.com/request/request). However, sometimes an image doesn't exist, which is exposed by S3 as a status code 403. I'm struggling to see how I can pipe in case of success (200) but take an alternative action in case of a non-200.

Using the abort() method seemed like the way to go but getting an `r.abort is not a function`, even though it should be available on the request.

```
// context: inside a request handler, where `res` is the response to write to
const r = request(url)
  .on('response', function (response) {
    if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
      r.abort(); //failing
      // I want to stop the piping here and do whatever instead.
    }
  })
  .pipe(res);
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question: don't start piping until sure it's correct:

```
 request(url)
    .on('response', function (r) {
      if (r.statusCode !== 200) {
        //take other action
      }
      r.pipe(res);
    })
```